# Does Azure Hub and Spoke vnet peering support multiple appliances in the Hub vnet?

Tags: azure, peering, virtual-appliances

**Azure Hub and Spoke topology**

[image: Azure Hub and Spoke topology]

As is shown above with Hub and Spoke topology, does it support multiple NVA's in the Hub vnet and force traffic to traverse through them (one by one)?

In my test, multiple NVA's work when everything is in the same vnet.

When you put client and server in two separate Spoke vnet's, you can only see traffic hit the first appliance, and then off the radar after exiting it, but then arrives at the destination in the other vnet.

Comment: with free appliance you will have some limitation, this were free and paid appliance split in termes of features. Contact BArracuda, this is were the are good at !

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The mask used in UDR must match with the networks that you defined in your vnet. e.g. you cannot summarize using 0.0.0.0/0 if you had 10.0.0.0/24 and 10.0.1.0/24, use those two networks in the UDR worked.